# How to allocate a memory to a given pointer to an array in C++

Tags: c++, malloc

I've tried to allocate a memory this way:

**main:**

```
X** a;
func(a);
```

**func:**

```
func(X** a){
   int size = 5;
   X* array = (X*)malloc(5*sizeof(X));
   //some writing to the array..
   a = &array;
}
```

If using the debugger I see that when I am in the function `func` everything is okay = i can write to the array and `a` really points to the array but the moment I am back to the main I something changes and I can't access the array through `a` (on the debugger it writes something like: `Target request failed: Cannot access memory at address 0x909090c3` and so on).

Where is my mistake?

Note: It does compile but has a run-time problem if trying to access (print for example) the array in the **main** section.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the local pointer `a` to the address of the local pointer `array`, when you want to set the target of `a` to the value of `array`:

```
*a = array;
```

and call it as

```
X * a;
func(&a);
```

It would be less confusing to return the pointer (i.e. `X * func()`).

Also, you've tagged this C++ not C, so you shouldn't be using `malloc`; use the standard containers, or if they don't work for you, allocate using `new` and manage the memory with a smart pointer.

Answer (score 7):

You have to change your main like this:

```
X* a;     // create an uninitialized pointer
func(&a); // pass the address of that pointer to the function
```

And inside your function, do this:

```
void func(X** a){
   int size = 5;
   X* array = (X*)malloc(5*sizeof(X));
   //some writing to the array..
   *a = array; // change the value of the pointer to point to the array
               // you allocated
}
```

Note that in C++ the way to go would be to use an `std::vector<X>`:

```
std::vector<X> func() {
    std::vector<X> buffer(5);
    // do stuff with buffer
    return buffer;
}

std::vector<X> foo = func();
```

This would create a new `vector` inside the function and return a copy of that vector to the caller. Note that the copy would be optimized away.

Comment: Note that in C++, if you were to allocate on the heap, you'd use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the local copy of your variable `a`, it will not propagate to the outside of function (ie. the calling scope). Easiest solution to your problem is to pass `a` by reference, but you can also pass it using a pointer and dereferencing the pointer inside of your function.

See the below examples.

---

### Using a reference

```
void func (X*& a) {
  X* array = (X*) malloc (5*sizeof(X));

  a = array;
}
```

...

```
  X* a;

  func (a);
```

The ampersand on the line below states that a is being passed by reference, ie. changing it inside the function will make the change propagate to parameter the caller used.

```
void func (X*& a) {
```

---

### Using a *pointer-to-pointer*

This can be hard to comprehend if you are inexperienced when it comes to pointers, but we will make `func` take a *pointer-to-pointer* as it's parameter and pass in the address of variable `a` from main.

Upon dereferencing the *pointer-to-pointer* we can safely store away the information we want.

```
void func (X** pointer_to_a) {
  X* array = (X*) malloc (5*sizeof(X));

  *pointer_to_a = array;
}
```

...

```
 X * a;

 func (&a); // pass in address of a
```

---

## NOTE

Since you are writing C++ (stated by question title and tag) you should not be using `std::malloc`, instead refer to `operator new`.

Comment: ... and should also consider `std::vector<X>`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. As for the first part, there is a very specific reason why I needed to use malloc instead of operator new. Of course that normally I would use new. I didn't mention as it wasn't exactly part of the question but thanks.

Comment: @user550413 See my edit, you got two options to solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In `main`, `a` is a pointer to a pointer. That means that two things have to exist: the block of memory, and a pointer pointing to it. Then `a` can point to that pointer. In your attempt, that middle pointer is being allocated on the stack of `func`, and when `func` returns, it's destroyed, so that's not going to work.

You could do this:

```
X* pa;
X** a = &pa;
func(a);

func(X** a){
   int size = 5;
   X* array = (X*)malloc(5*sizeof(X));
   //some writing to the array..
   *a = array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think it over: 
    a = &array;
array is a local variable allocated on heap, &array will be junk when its scope is over (the function body).